# Collapse and intersect data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregates

I have two `data.frame`s which have a 3 columns:
1. `id` - a unique key

2. `target` - semicolon separated unique values
3. `source` - similar for each of the data frames but different for the two `data.frame`s.

Here's simulated data:

```
set.seed(1)
df.1 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),10,replace=F)],
                   target=sapply(1:10,function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5,replace=F)],collapse=";")),
                   source="A",stringsAsFactors=F)

df.2 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5,replace=F)],
                   target=sapply(1:5,function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5,replace=F)],collapse=";")),
                   source="B",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I'm looking for a function that will collapse the two `data.frame`s together and will create 3 columns:

1.`intersected.targets` - semicolon separated unique values that are intersected between the two `data.frame`s

2.`source1.targets` - targets that are unique to the first `data.frame`

3.`source2.targets` - targets that are unique to the second `data.frame`

So for the example above the resulting `data.frame` will be:

```
> res.df
   id intersected.targets sourceA.targets sourceB.targets
1   G                  NA       F;E;Q;I;X            <NA>
2   J                  NA       M;R;X;I;Y            <NA>
3   N                  NA       Y;F;P;C;Z            <NA>
4   U                  NA       K;A;J;U;H            <NA>
5   E                  NA       M;O;L;E;S            <NA>
6   S                  NA       R;T;C;Q;J            <NA>
7   W                  NA       V;Q;S;M;L            <NA>
8   M                  NA       U;A;L;Q;P            <NA>
9   B                  NA       C;H;M;P;I            <NA>
10  X                  NA            <NA>       G;L;S;B;T
11  H                  NA            <NA>       I;U;Z;H;K
12  Y                  NA            <NA>       L;R;J;H;Q
13  O                  NA            <NA>       F;R;C;Z;D
14  L                  V       M;K;F;B       X;J;R;Y
```

Comment: You could start with `library(data.table) ; dcast(rbind(setDT(df.1), setDT(df.2)), id ~ source, value.var = "target")`. Not sure what you want in the `intersected.targets` column as you haven't specified it in your desired output

Comment: You don't need this modification (not to mention that your code didn't work) because you already have a common "V" there

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Edited accordingly

Comment: I'm guessing @DavidArenburg has only temporarily deleted his response and is editing it and if that's the case I was going to suggest that he continue with datatable methods using conversion to list columns for the source columns and then run `setdiff`,  by=id.

Comment: @42- Nah, I don't have time for this, you can post a solution if have any.

Comment: Rats, I had gotten as far as you using base methods but was kind of hoping you were further along and I could give up. (I think you're a lot better with data.table than I.)

Comment: concat string, table characters, subset >1, join string?

Answer (score 2):

The pain in the butt in this type of data cleaning, as @42- mentions, is unlisting data frames of lists.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- full_join(df.1, df.2) %>% 
  spread(source, target)  %>%
  mutate(intersect_targets = str_c(A,B,sep = ";"))

df[,4][!is.na(df[,4])] <- names(do.call("c",lapply(df$intersect_targets, function(x) 
which(table(str_split(x, ";"))>1))))

a <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) {
str_split(df[x,2:3],";")
})

sa <-  do.call("c",lapply(mapply(setdiff,a[1,], a[2,]),paste0, collapse = ","))
sb <- do.call("c",lapply(mapply(setdiff,a[2,], a[1,]), paste0, collapse = ","))

df[,2:3] <-cbind(sa,sb)

 head(df)
  id         A         B intersect_targets
1  B C,H,M,P,I        NA              <NA>
2  E M,O,L,E,S        NA              <NA>
3  G F,E,Q,I,X        NA              <NA>
4  H        NA I,U,Z,H,K              <NA>
5  J M,R,X,I,Y        NA              <NA>
6  L   M,K,F,B   X,J,R,Y                 V
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you removed teh intersecting elements from the input sets.

Comment: It's possible we could have done it on the non-list version with something like: `A <- gsub( paste( ";*, intersect_targets), "",  A)`. Kind of frustrating to spend an hour at @AM on a question and then get no upvote, eh?

Comment: You have mine. Didn't get a chance to read it start to finish until just now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a continuation of DavidArenberg's deleted answer that taught me the notion of creating a list column in a data.table.  I didn't know how to properly implement my idea of using `setdiff` row by row but eventually after multiple searches found an answer by Frank that does it. Here is David's (partial) answer:

=====
Here's a possible solution on a different seed that have more than one intersections and more than one letter in a single intersection

```
#Generating Data

set.seed(123)
df.1 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),10,replace=F)],
                   target=sapply(1:10,function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5,
                                                                replace=F)],collapse=";")),
                   source="A",stringsAsFactors=F)

df.2 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5, replace=F)],
                   target=sapply(1:5,function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS),5, 
                                                               replace=F)],collapse=";")),
                   source="B",stringsAsFactors=F)
#Solution

library(data.table) 
library(stringi)
res <- dcast(rbind(setDT(df.1), setDT(df.2)), id ~ source, value.var = "target")
res[!is.na(A) & !is.na(B), intersected.targets := 
                             stri_extract_all(A, regex = gsub(";", "|", B, fixed = TRUE))]
res
```

==========================

So I used his listifying code to make an A2and B2 column that are the list-version of A and B

```
res[ , A2 := stri_extract_all(A, regex = "[[:alpha:]]") ]
 res[ , B2 := stri_extract_all(B, regex = "[[:alpha:]]") ]
```

Then used `Map()` to do a row by row setdiff:

```
res[, SourceA := Map( setdiff, A2, intersected.targets)]
res[, SourceB := Map( setdiff, B, intersected.targets)]
 res
#-------------------------------
    id         A         B intersected.targets        A2        B2   SourceA   SourceB
 1:  A M;S;F;H;X        NA                NULL M,S,F,H,X        NA M,S,F,H,X        NA
 2:  C        NA T;P;R;A;K                NULL        NA T,P,R,A,K        NA T,P,R,A,K
 3:  G        NA G;Q;K;S;C                NULL        NA G,Q,K,S,C        NA G,Q,K,S,C
 4:  H Y;L;Q;N;C        NA                NULL Y,L,Q,N,C        NA Y,L,Q,N,C        NA
 5:  J X;R;P;W;O F;J;O;I;C                   O X,R,P,W,O F,J,O,I,C   X,R,P,W   F,J,I,C
 6:  K D;K;J;I;Z        NA                NULL D,K,J,I,Z        NA D,K,J,I,Z        NA
 7:  Q D;F;L;G;S        NA                NULL D,F,L,G,S        NA D,F,L,G,S        NA
 8:  R        NA L;U;T;S;J                NULL        NA L,U,T,S,J        NA L,U,T,S,J
 9:  T X;G;B;H;U        NA                NULL X,G,B,H,U        NA X,G,B,H,U        NA
10:  U S;N;O;G;D        NA                NULL S,N,O,G,D        NA S,N,O,G,D        NA
11:  W Z;W;Q;S;A        NA                NULL Z,W,Q,S,A        NA Z,W,Q,S,A        NA
12:  X B;L;T;C;M        NA                NULL B,L,T,C,M        NA B,L,T,C,M        NA
13:  Z F;D;S;U;I L;Y;V;U;D                 D,U F,D,S,U,I L,Y,V,U,D     F,S,I     L,Y,V
```

I'm leaving the clean-up as a student exercise.